# How to relate LatLong and State columns on PowerBI

Tags: spatial, csv, powerbi

I have two separate tables, one with `latitude` and `longitude` columns (for locations in the USA), and the other with the US state abbreviation (TX, AZ, CA, etc).

Is there a way to count the number of rows in the `LatLong` table that fall within each state in the other table using PowerBI?

Comment: what database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Without ever using PowerBI, without even knowing what it is, no. Highly unlikely.

You'll have to pull in Shapefiles that represent the states from the Census or like data-source. Then you'll have to construct points representing the cords and run point-in-polygon on the result.

Check out

- [Geographic Information Systems GIS.StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)